# specify group_by variables programmatically in targets workflow with static branching

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I'm using the targets package in R to organize data processing and analysis for some studies that involve multiple different data sources (surveys, performance metrics on different tasks, etc).  Because some of the tasks produce large quantities of data, I have to use dynamic branching to limit how much data I'm trying to load into R at any given time.

I've started using static branching as well to better organize the workflow, but I'm running into an issue, and I'm hoping there is a work-around.  I would like to be able to define the variables I want to group by in `tar_group_by` or `tar_group_select` in my list/tibble of parameters to send to `tar_map`, as seen in the following reprex:

```r
library(targets)

targets::tar_dir({
  targets::tar_script({
    library(targets)
    library(tarchetypes)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    df1 <- data.frame(
      g1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
      x = 1:6,
      y = 1:6
    ) |>
      group_by(g1)
    
    df2 <- data.frame(
      g1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
      g2 = rep(LETTERS[4:6], 2),
      x = 1:6,
      y = 1:6
    ) |>
      group_by(g2)
    
    list(
      label = c("group1", "group2"),
      source = c("df1", "df2") |> syms(),
      by = c("g1", 'g2')  # group by g1 for df1 and g2 for df2
    ) |>
      tar_map(
        names = "label",
        tar_group_select(
          result,
          identity(source),
          # by = 'g1' # works (because g1 is defined in both data sets)
          by = by
        )
      )
  })
  
  tar_manifest()
  tar_make()
})
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 3.3.6     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
#> ✔ tibble  3.1.7     ✔ dplyr   1.0.9
#> ✔ tidyr   1.2.0     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
#> ✔ readr   2.1.2     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 3.3.6     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
#> ✔ tibble  3.1.7     ✔ dplyr   1.0.9
#> ✔ tidyr   1.2.0     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
#> ✔ readr   2.1.2     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
#> • start target result_group1
#> ✖ error target result_group1
#> • end pipeline: 0.105 seconds
#> Error : tar_group() must take a grouped data frame from dplyr::group_by()
#> ✖ Problem with the pipeline.
#> ℹ Show errors: tar_meta(fields = error, complete_only = TRUE)
#> ℹ Learn more: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html
#> Error:
#> ! problem with the pipeline.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Replacing `by = by` with `by = g1` or `by = 'g1'` works just fine, so this seems to be an issue where `tar_map` isn't looking to my list to get a result for `by`.  Any solutions/work-arounds that don't involve hand-coding all my tar_group_* statements?

(I usually use `tar_group_by` when they are not in a static branch.  I was hoping `tar_group_select` would allow me to pass my group variables in the context of `tar_map`, but that doesn't seem to be working.)

Comment: Can you use `by = starts_with('g')`

Comment: This would work in the reprex, but in the actual data sets, I'm often grouping by multiple variables (with a variety of different names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tar_map()` works on the `command` and `pattern` settings of regular target objects, but it doesn't see the `by` argument of special target factories like `tar_group_select()`. So instead, I recommend something `tar_eval()`, which straightforwardly substitutes symbols in the expression you give it.

```r
# _targets.R file
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df1 <- data.frame(
  g1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
  x = 1:6,
  y = 1:6
) |>
  group_by(g1)

df2 <- data.frame(
  g1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
  g2 = rep(LETTERS[4:6], 2),
  x = 1:6,
  y = 1:6
) |>
  group_by(g2)

tar_eval(
  values = list(
    name = c("result1", "result2"),
    label = c("group1", "group2"),
    source = c("df1", "df2") |> syms(),
    by = c("g1", "g2")  # group by g1 for df1 and g2 for df2
  ),
  tar_group_select(
    name = name,
    command = identity(source),
    by = all_of(by)
  )
)
```